# How to retrieve Mongoose Model based on Express params

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How can I dynamically retrieve a mongoose model wherein the name depends on the req.params.model?

Here is an example of my Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SmartSchema = new Schema({
SmartPriority: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
SmartClassification: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("smarts", SmartSchema);
```

My code below doesn't work.

```
router.delete(
"/delete/:model/:id",
passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
(req, res) => {
    let { model, id } = req.params;
    model.deleteOne({ _id: id }) //model = Mongoose Model/ eg: Smart Schema
        .then(res.status(200).json({ msg: "Success" }))
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({ msg: err });
        });
}
);
```

Comment: hi @danilodeveloper. Here is the error message: "TypeError: model.deleteOne is not a function"

Comment: Great. Can you share you `JwtStrategy` code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set require for **model** file.

```
let { model, id } = req.params;
var Model = require('../models/' + model);
Model.deleteOne({ _id: id })....
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: After your answer I realized what Brian wants. **Good answer**! Probably this is what @Brian is looking for. Upvoted ;)

Comment: Thanks! This helped me